# How can i install Ubuntu 20.04 in Arm laptop

Tags: arm

How to install ubuntu in Arm os, i am facing difficulties while installing it was throwing error as machine type error, please kindly let me know what are the steps for installation and making bootable pendrive

Comment: My assumption is you downloaded the wrong ISO.  Can you tell us which ISO you've downloaded?

Comment: I have installed "ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso", Could you please suggest a suitable OS for it.
The process of making bootable pendrive for ARM processor is same as normal system?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu do not ship an iso for ARM hardware 20.04 except for Ubuntu Base.

See [this Canonical reference](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/20.04/release/)

Comment: Even after the "Ubuntu Base" software is installed on a laptop, I guess you can run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` for adding GUI capability to it.